# C# Close MDI Child On Load from User Control

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, mdichild

Im trying to close a MDI Child on Form_Load but im getting the error "Error creating window handle."

i want to verify is the user have access to that form and if dont have access then close the form.

```
if (!Functions.Contains("Access"))
{
                    var frm = ((Form)this.Parent);
                    frm.Close();
}
```

Comment: Check for access *before* calling form.Show()

Comment: the issue is that i want my form to inherit from another that will have all the code for security, that way i dont have to preocupate to validate each button for security

Answer (score 1):

Here i have doubt in your question: either you want to close your parent form or mdi child form. you have written code to get reference of parent form but as per your paragraph you want to close your child form.

**you must have to use "Shown" event to do this.**

for parent closing Example :

```
 private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

            Application.Exit();
        }
```

only for child closing :

```
private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

        }
```